# I am building a t-shirt online shop and I am taking designs from pixabay

Tags: website-design

I am building an online store and I am using designs for my t-shirts from pixabay.com and it says there free for commercial use. So does it mean I can print it on my t-shirts and sell it? 
Example https://pixabay.com/en/puppy-dog-cute-doggy-pit-bull-150399/

Answer (score 2):

*"Free for commercial use"* means it's free to use on products or items you are selling.